# Creating a Behavior for a continuously measurable phenomenon

Tags: haskell, ghcjs, reflex

I would like to create a `Behavior t a` from an `IO a`, with the intended semantics that the IO action would be run every time the behavior is `sample`d:

```
{- language FlexibleContexts #-}
import Reflex.Dom
import Control.Monad.Trans

onDemand :: (MonadWidget t m, MonadIO (PullM t)) => IO a -> m (Behavior t a)
```

I hoped I could do this by just executing the `measurement` in a `pull`:

```
onDemand measure = return $ pull (liftIO measure)
```

However, the resulting `Behavior` never changes after an initial `measure`ment.

The workaround I could come up with was to create a dummy `Behavior` that changes "frequently enough" and then create a fake dependency on that:

```
import Data.Time.Clock as Time

hold_ :: (MonadHold t m, Reflex t) => Event t a -> m (Behavior t ())
hold_ = hold () . (() <$)

onDemand :: (MonadWidget t m, MonadIO (PullM t)) => IO a -> m (Behavior t a)
onDemand measure = do
    now <- liftIO Time.getCurrentTime
    tick <- hold_ =<< tickLossy (1/1200) now
    return $ pull $ do
        _ <- sample tick
        liftIO measure
```

This then works as expected; but since `Behavior`s can only be sampled on demand anyway, this shouldn't be necessary.

What is the correct way to create a `Behavior` for a continuous, observable-at-any-time phenomenon?

Comment: I don't know how to do what you want, but I will observe that what you are asking for is semantically very strange -- the "meaning" of such a behavior could change based on how observers interacted with the behavior. I don't know your FRP framework enough to know for sure, but I would expect that behaviors are intended to be independent of observation -- and the fact that observation can change how the "meaning" is calculated at runtime is merely an implementation detail rather than something that is meant to be exposed to the programmer.

Comment: Is it something like `Signal` in Elm you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doing this in `Spider` looks impossible. `Internal` reasoning ahead.

In the `Spider` implementation of `Reflex`, one of the possible [`Behavior`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/reflex/docs/Reflex-Spider-Internal.html#t:Behavior)s is to pull the value.

```
data Behavior a
   = BehaviorHold !(Hold a)
   | BehaviorConst !a
   | BehaviorPull !(Pull a)
```

A [`Pull`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/reflex/docs/Reflex-Spider-Internal.html#t:Pull)ed value consists of how to compute the value when needed, `pullCompute`, and a cached value to avoid unnecessary re-computation, `pullValue`.

```
data Pull a
   = Pull { pullValue :: !(IORef (Maybe (PullSubscribed a)))
          , pullCompute :: !(BehaviorM a)
          }
```

Ignoring the ugly environment of [`BehaviorM`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/reflex/docs/Reflex-Spider-Internal.html#t:BehaviorM), `liftIO` lifts an `IO` computation the obvious way, it runs it when the `BehaviorM` needs to be sampled. In the `Pull`, your behavior is observed once but isn't re-observed because the cached value isn't invalidated.

The cached value [`PullSubscribed a`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/reflex/docs/Reflex-Spider-Internal.html#t:PullSubscribed) consists of the value `a`, a list of other values that need to be invalidated if this value is invalidated, and some boring memory management stuff.

```
data PullSubscribed a
   = PullSubscribed { pullSubscribedValue :: !a
                    , pullSubscribedInvalidators :: !(IORef [Weak Invalidator])
                    -- ... boring memory stuff
                    }
```

An [`Invalidator`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/reflex/docs/Reflex-Spider-Internal.html#t:Invalidator) is a quantified `Pull` that's enough to get the memory reference to recursively read the invalidators to invalidate and write the cached value to `Nothing`.

To pull constantly we'd like to be able to constantly invalidate our own `BehaviorM`. When executed, the environment passed to the `BehaviorM` has a copy of its own invalidator, which is used by dependencies of the `BehaviorM` to invalidate it when they themselves become invalid.

From the internal implementation of [`readBehaviorTracked`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/reflex-0.4.0/docs/src/Reflex-Spider-Internal.html#readBehaviorTracked]) there seems to be no way that the behavior's own invalidator (`wi`) can ever end up in the list of subscribers that are invalidated when it is sampled (`invsRef`).

```
    a <- liftIO $ runReaderT (unBehaviorM $ pullCompute p) $ Just (wi, parentsRef)
    invsRef <- liftIO . newIORef . maybeToList =<< askInvalidator
    -- ...
    let subscribed = PullSubscribed
          { pullSubscribedValue = a
          , pullSubscribedInvalidators = invsRef
          -- ...
          }
```

Outside of the internals, if there does exist a way to constantly sample a `Behavior` it would involve a `MonadFix (PullM t)` instance or mutual recursion through fixing of [`pull`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/reflex-0.4.0/docs/Reflex-Class.html#v:pull) and [`sample`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/reflex-0.4.0/docs/Reflex-Class.html#v:sample):

```
onDemand :: (Reflex t, MonadIO (PullM t)) => IO a -> Behavior t a
onDemand read = b
    where
        b = pull go
        go = do
             sample b
             liftIO read
```

I don't have a `Reflex` environment to try this in, but I don't think the results will be pretty.

Comment: Does `reflex-dom` has its own `Reflex` instance, or does it use the same `Spider` type underneath? I'd be happy with a `reflex-dom`-only solution.

Comment: FWIW, your suggestion of `fix $ \timestamp -> pull $ sample timestamp >> liftIO read` causes a divergence/infinite loop, as expected.

Answer (score 2):

I've been experimenting with this for a while and found a workaround. It seems to work with the latest version of reflex to date. The trick is to forcefully invalidate the cached value every time you evaluate a given `IO` action.

```
import qualified Reflex.Spider.Internal as Spider

onDemand :: IO a -> Behavior t a
onDemand ma = SpiderBehavior . Spider.Behavior
            . Spider.BehaviorM . ReaderT $ computeF
  where
    computeF (Nothing, _) = unsafeInterleaveIO ma
    computeF (Just (invW,_), _) = unsafeInterleaveIO $ do
        toReconnect <- newIORef []
        _ <- Spider.invalidate toReconnect [invW]
        ma
```

It is important to use `unsafeInterleaveIO` to run the invalidator as late as possible, so that it invalidates an existing thing.

There is another problem with this code: I ignore `toReconnect` reference and the result of `invalidate` function. In current version of reflex, the latter is always empty, so it should not cause any problems.
But I am not sure about `toReconnect`: from the code, it seems that if it has some subscribed switches, they might break if not treated properly. Though I am not sure if this kind of behavior can have switches subscribed or not.

**UPDATE** for those who really want to implement this:
The code above can deadlock in some complicated setups.
My solutions was to perform invalidation slightly after the computation itself in a separate thread.
[Here is the complete code snippet](https://github.com/achirkin/reflex-animated/blob/master/src/Reflex/Dom/Widget/Animation.hs#L189-L213).
The solution by the link seems to work correctly (using it for almost a year now in production).