# Representing timestamps

Tags: haskell, ghcjs, reflex

I would like to represent the timestamp coming from an [`HTMLMediaElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement). Its defining characteristics are:

- Its value is represented as a `Double`
- It can be queried at any time using `getCurrentTime :: IO Double` (as partially applied on a given `HTMLMediaElement`)
- It is potentially continuously changing (whenever the media player is playing)

My initial plan was to [represent it as a `Behavior t Double` that re-runs the `IO Double` every time it is observed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35957463/477476), but that hasn't worked out too well.

Things I've tried:

- Using a `Behavior` that is prodded under the hood at a fixed frequency, as described in [the workaround section of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35957463/477476)
- Passing an `Event t ()` representing the desired sampling frequency, and returning an `Event t Double` that holds the coinciding timestamps

I don't really like either -- the first one either couples the *behaviour* (sorry) too much to my specific use case (if I use the eventual sampling frequency I'll use in my app) or seems wasteful (if I use something like 1 kHz sampling when creating the `Behavior` just to then sample it at 60 Hz on the application end), and the second is quite inflexible if you want to do more than one thing with the timestamp at different sampling rates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, using an `Event` to explicitly sample the time (your second option) value is your best bet.  We haven't yet created a way to write `Behavior`s that lazily poll outside resources, although that is something that I hope we'll be able to get done soon.

Keep in mind that, with your second option, you don't necessarily need to use a specific sampling rate; instead, you can sample on-demand, and even have multiple locations doing that sampling.  It's not perfect, but I hope that'll let you get the job done!